Giving charity after the person refuses to take it
If a person donated 50 for the shul to get a new air conditioner. A week later the Gabbai gives it back saying we raised the funds without you. Is there person still obligated to give the charity. Please explain the reason.

According to this article, since it was a earmarked for a specific purpose which no longer exists, the contribution is nullified:

if the fundraiser set a specific goal that was known beforehand, every
donor thought that his donation was going towards that goal. Had they
had known that the goal was already met, they would not have given the
donation; therefore, it can be said that the donations given above the
goal are like the cases of the Teshuvos HaRosh where the donation is
being given in error and, if possible, should be returned to the
donors. If this is not possible, the money should be given to a
similar charity.

